# Any alternative in R to encapsulate and pass data like objects do

Tags: r, oop, functional-programming, parameter-passing, encapsulation

The followings are the data to be passed:

```
get.member.x = function() {
    return( list(info.file='x') )
}

get.member.y = function() {
    return( list(info.file='y') )
}
```

I want to use the data in a function. I can pass these data in two ways: 1. Global variables 2. Argument passing.

This is how to pass the data using global variables:

```
test = function() {
    print(get()$info.file)
}

main3 = function(){
    get <<- get.member.x
    test()
    get <<- get.member.y
    test()
}
```

This is how to pass the data using argument passing:

```
test2 = function(get) {
    print(get()$info.file)
}

main2 = function(){
    get = get.member.x
    test2(get)
    get = get.member.y
    test2(get)
}
```

The result of executing the code is here:

```
> main2()
[1] "x"
[1] "y"

> main3()
[1] "x"
[1] "y"
```

Now, I wonder if there is any better alternative than these two ways to pass data. Both methods have some disadvantages.

Using global variables is dangerous, because it has side effects on other parts of the code.

Using argument passing is safe but it clutters the function arguments overall the code. In every function where I need these data members, I will have to pass the data as arguments to the caller and called functions.

If there was a way to encapsulate data members in objects, we could overcome these two issue.

Is there any better alternative way of solving this problem? Or do you think that the current way is better than encapsulating the data in objects?

*Update:*

#### What do I try to do with this?

My intention is to change the behaviour of functions without changing the code of the functions such that common code is reused. Consider the following code:

```
test.duplicate = function() {
    result = common.fun.1()
    result = common.fun.2()
}
common.fun.1 = function() {
    # common steps
    result = different.fun.1()
    # common steps
}
common.fun.2 = function() {
    # common steps
    result = different.fun.2()
    # common steps
}
```

Above, common.fun.1 and common.fun.2 have a lot of common code. But since one line is different, I have duplicated all the common code.

To prevent the duplication of common code, I can encapsulate the changing part into an external parameter injected into the function:

```
test.reuse = function() {
    result = common.fun()
}
common.fun = function() {
    # common steps
    result = get()$different.fun()
    # common steps
}
```

Now, in order to change the behaviour we need to change the injected parameter:

```
get.member.x = function() {
    return( list(different.fun=different.fun.1) )
}

get.member.y = function() {
    return( list(different.fun=different.fun.2) )
}

get <<- get.member.x
test.reuse()
get <<- get.member.y
test.reuse()
```

So, we eliminated the duplicated code while changing the behaviour of the function.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I feel like you shouldn't be doing any of the things in the code you've shown here, but it's hard to say what would be better since you haven't given us the larger problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Reading it again, I guess you probably want to look at Reference Classes. Maybe start with [Hadley's tutorial](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html).

Comment: Why not use a list with multiple objects? -  `list(x="....", y="...")`

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the reference. Reference Classes look suitable for my problem.

Coming to your first question: What do I try to do? My intention is to change the behaviour of functions without changing the code of the functions in order to prevent duplicate code. I will update my question with concrete example of that problem.